# how to change the text location on a button in the gui

Tags: autohotkey

autohotkey
i want to change the location of the text that is created on a button instead of being centered in the middle of the button,  to be on the top part of the button (text size 10) then have a short discription of what the button does in the bottom part (text size 5 )

[image: button]

these are the two kinds of buttons i want to create.
Button 1 has large text at the top and then some discription in the bottom part in a smaller text size.
Button 2 just has a larger test at the top part

i am a new with autohotkey and dont know its full capabilities, is this something that is possible with autohotkey

Curently i am thinking of creating a the button with just the larger text at the top part and then i will overlay it with text that is created with a diffrent command with a smaller text size. but this method will take quite a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to position button text to the top or bottom, but you can do it by adding lines above or below your text. In my example below I added four lines below the text to push it up. Though it appears positioned towards the top, it is still in the middle vertically. (Note that there are `Left` and `Right` options for horizontal positioning.)

```
Gui , New
Gui , Font , S10
Gui , Add , Button , w150 h150 Section , Button 1`n`n`n`n
Gui , Add , Button , w150 h150 x+m , Button 2`n`n`n`n
Gui , Font , S5
Gui , Add , Text , xs+25 ys+90 , this button runs the command
Gui , Show
Return
```

Please also see the help documentation as it does a great job of explaining how to use GUIs and what options are available.
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm